# Using ENUM Type as Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, enums, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have given schema of database as given.[image]

i want ENUM Type for column _product_fabric and _product_size of _product table to _product_fabric_data table's primary key _product_fabric_id(int) and _product_size_data table's _product_size_id(int) respectively.
is it good idea to use ENUM type Foreign key? if yes, then how do i apply it?
also what consequences may occur in future? if there is better solution, suggest me.

Comment: `ENUM` is handled internally as a small number, I don't see any reason why it couldn't be a FK.

Comment: The FK has to be the same datatype as the column it references. So you'll have to use the same `ENUM` for the PK in the target table.